# ReactNativeAsyncStorage it is not working with firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I had a problem with the persistence in the web version, then I added a conditional to use differents persistences depending if it is web or mobile. The problem now is that in the mobile version I am getting a warn:

> WARN  [2024-01-18T19:24:16.586Z]  @firebase/auth: Auth (10.7.1): You
> are initializing Firebase Auth for React Native without providing
> AsyncStorage. Auth state will default to memory persistence and will
> not persist between sessions. In order to persist auth state, install
> the package "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" and provide it
> to initializeAuth:
>
> import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from
> 'firebase/auth'; import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from
> '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'; const auth =
> initializeAuth(app, {   persistence:
> getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage) });

This is my code:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {
  initializeAuth,
  getReactNativePersistence,
  browserLocalPersistence,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { setPersistence } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

// Inicializar Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_authDomain,
  projectId: process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_projectId,
  storageBucket: process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_messagingSenderId,
  appId: process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_appId,
  measurementId: process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_measurementId,
};

export const FIREBASE_APP = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const FIREBASE_DB = getFirestore(FIREBASE_APP);
export const FIREBASE_AUTH = initializeAuth(FIREBASE_APP);

// Conditional persistence configuration
if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
  // settings for (Android/iOS)
  const reactNativePersistence = getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage);
  setPersistence(FIREBASE_AUTH, reactNativePersistence)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error with React Native: ', error);
    });
} else {
    // settings for web
  setPersistence(FIREBASE_AUTH, browserLocalPersistence)
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error with the web: ', error);
  });
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that `Platform.OS` is not giving you the correct value here: `if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {`? If I look at the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-module) it never seems to return `web`, so you might want to check `if (['ios','android'].includes(Platform.OS)) {`

Comment: no, I am saying that even though I'm using ReactNativeAsyncStorage, it still says I'm not using it.

Comment: Although use for example: `if (Platform.OS === 'android') {` still keep the same problem